# windows 10 audio stuttering

Tags: windows, audio

Running ryzen r5 1600 on a gigabyte ab350 gaming 3 mobo. Audio has been stuttering for the past month. Reinstalling audio drivers did not help. Using latencymon, I identified that storport was causing huge latency spikes on the order of 100ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:
Device manager -> IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers -> AMD SATA controller -> disable
latency is back to <200us. no more audio stuttering.